# combination unique with one column null

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I got a table example:

```
create table the_entity
(
 id integer,
 number integer not null,
 chair  integer null,
 primary key(id)
);
```

i want that the combination of the columns number and chair is unique. Column chair is nullable. Is this possible without using **filtered index** ?

Answer (score 1):

A filtered index is the only way to do that and allow for multiple `null`s for the same `number`. A unique constraint/unique index will allow one `null` per `number`.

The answers to a similar question on dba.stackexchange explain more: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/80514/why-does-a-unique-constraint-allow-only-one-null